# TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, request

I prefer to use promises rather than callbacks so I've used `util.promisify`.

```
`use strict`;

const util = require(`util`),
    request = util.promisify(require(`request`)),
    fs = require(`fs`).promises;

module.exports = async (message, api) => {
    const end = api.sendTypingIndicator(message.threadID);
    const data = await request({ url: `https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search`, followAllRedirects: true });
    const [json] = JSON.parse(data.body);
    console.log(fs);
    const image = await request(json.url);
    await fs.writeFile(`kitty.png`, image.body, `binary`);
    const attachments = {attachment: fs.createReadStream(`kitty.png`)};
    await fs.unlink(`kitty.png`);
    end();
    return attachments;
};
```

I've received `TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function` at `const attachments = {attachment: fs.createReadStream('kitty.png')};` line. How can I solve that?

Comment: What's your node version? The promises API is a relatively late addition

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`fs.promises` is not a superset of `fs`.  While it replaces some methods on `fs` with methods of the same core name that return a promise, it does not have everything on it that the plain `fs` has.

`createReadStream()` is a method on the regular `require('fs')` object, not on `require('fs').promises`.

This is why it is **not** recommended that you do this:

```
fs = require('fs').promises;
```

Because then it misleads everyone, including yourself into thinking that `fs` is the core nodejs fs module.  It's not.

Instead, I would recommend this:

```
const util = require('util'),
    request = util.promisify(require('request')),
    fs = require('fs'),
    fsp = fs.promises;
```

Then, you can use both `fs` and `fsp` as appropriate including `fs.createReadStream()`.

Yes, this does seem a bit untidy.  Perhaps the `fs` module conversion to promises is only partially complete and someday you can use `fs.promises` as a full replacement - I don't really know what the folks working on that module intend.  For now, you have to use both versions to get access to full functionality.

---

Also, be careful about `util.promisify(require('request'))`.  The request function does not use the standard asynchronous callback signature `(err, result)` since it passes three arguments to the callback `(err, response, body)`, not the usual two.  There are request derivative modules that are already promisified (`request-promise` and `request-promise-native`) that are fully ready to use with promises.

Also, the `request()` module has been deprecated now (as of 2020 and will not get any more new features) and a list of alternatives (all of which support a promise interface) is [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).